# How can I load a library view without the site navigation on header bar, but only containing the content?

Tags: master-page, view, library

I hope the question title is specific enough, but I'll elaborate further. I have a requirement to load various views in a library through an iframe. Furthermore, I need only need the actual content and not the site navigation that has the left bar and title row. I'm not even sure if what I'm trying to do is possible as it's a page that SharePoint created when I was in a library and made a new view.

I've used SharePoint Designer to copy one of these .aspx files to edit and tweak to this end. Here's an example URL for the page I'm trying to load in the iframe (the page won't actually load for you, but the url structure may inform you of...something?):

http://mySpServer/sites/mySpSite/Library/Forms/Education2.aspx

I know that this page utilizes the 'mySpSite' masterpage. Is it possible to have a view for a document library under a site use a different master page? Is it as simple as just editing the 'Education2.aspx' file or is it more than that?

I'm honestly a bit lost on this. Nevermind that I then need to figure out how to load this in an iframe, but I'm hoping the details at [this](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/The-Content-cannot-be-displayed-in-a-frame-Display-another-SharePoint-WebApplication-inside-an-iFrame-of-our-SharePoint-Site) link provide an accurate resolution for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the **IsDlg** parameter. You can add that to the end of a url as a query string and it tells SP to hide the nav and suitebar. So for example:

```
http://mySpServer/sites/mySpSite/Library/Forms/Education2.aspx?IsDlg=1
```

Here is a [blog post](https://davidlozzi.com/2014/03/25/we-all-know-what-sharepoint-isdlg-does-wait-what-the/) that describes how it works and a gotcha based on if the parameter is capitalized or not.